# why do i get the error "Missing JavaFX application class application.Main" when i run miglayout-javafx-5.2.jar to use MigPane?

Tags: javafx, miglayout

I have been trying to run my app with miglayout-javafx-5.2.jar, however every time I run the app, i get the an error, stating " Missing JavaFX application class application.Main".The screenshot in the link shows all the jar that i have downloaded.
  Thank you for your help!
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrLoN.png
Below is my code:

```
import org.tbee.javafx.scene.layout.MigPane;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;

public class Main extends Application {
 @Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        MigPane root = new MigPane();
        Button b = new Button("Cick me");
        root.add(b);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
 Error: "Missing JavaFX application class application.Main"

}
```

The jars i have downloaded for migpane are: 
 miglayout-javafx-5.2.jar
 miglayout-core-5.2.jar
I also have downloaded javafx in eclipse and it seems to work if i don't use migpane but when i use migpane i get the ERROR: "Missing JavaFX application class application.Main"

Comment: pls try to avoid screenshots and post its content directly to the your question

Comment: @Domso It doesn't allow me to do so however if you could tell me how to do it, i would certainly do it in a moment. Thank you

Comment: you should be able to edit your question and copy the code and the corresponding error message. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for more details

Comment: @Domso is this in the right format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been having similar issues with JavaFX as well, since Java 11+. It's probably caused by your application not being a module.

As a workaround, try this:

```
import org.tbee.javafx.scene.layout.MigPane;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(MainApplication.class, args);
  }

  public static class MainApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
      MigPane root = new MigPane();
      Button b = new Button("Cick me");
      root.add(b);
      Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
      primaryStage.setScene(scene);
      primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

And then launch `Main`.

Also: use an IDE and its code formatter, and stay away from `e.printStackTrace()`  :-)

Comment: Glad to hear! Could you then please accept the answer?

Comment: @Michael Jung how do I Set default CSS stylesheet for the whole Application in javafx? 
    Thanks for the help!

Comment: `scene.getStylesheets().add("test.css");` but please don't ask questions in comments, try Google or open a new question on SO.